# While loop stuck after processing last line of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, char

Below is my code which gets stuck at `if((p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]) != NULL)` in function `int Ms_SEnd(char **p_note_for_sm)`. After debugging the if condition I found that the value of `p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]` is not getting printed after processing upto last character of array and program unable to break from while loop and program gets stuck. I expect the value NULL in `p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]` to break this loop.

Kindly help me to find out the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SMAXLINE              200

int Ms_SEnd(char **p_note_for_sm)
{
    int msg_line_no = 0;

    while (msg_line_no <= 200)
    {
        if ((p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no], "\0") != 0)
            {
                printf("\nMsg In SM loop inside [%s]", p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            msg_line_no++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *chr_h_note_for_sm[SMAXLINE];
    char chr_h_note_1_new[8000] = "\0";
    char chr_h_note_new[8000] = "1 RECITE PREVIOUS MINUTES OF LAST AGM  2 DISCUSS THE BOD REPORT  3 DISCUSS THE AUDITORS REPORT  4 DISCUSS THE GENERAL BUDGET WITH THE PROFIT AND LOSS AND DISCUSS THE PERCENTAGE OF  CASH DIVIDENDS THAT WILL BE DISTRIBUTED  5 INDEMNIFY THE BOD  6 ELECT THE AUDITORS FOR THE YEAR 2019  7 DISCUSS OTHER ISSUES";
    int l_tail_pos = 0;
    int l_counter = 0;
    int msg_line_no = 0;
    int rownum = 1;
    int l_temp = 0;
    int l_length = 305;
    while (l_tail_pos < l_length)
    {
        chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter] = (char *)calloc(36, sizeof(char));

        if ((l_length - l_tail_pos) < 35)
        {
            for (l_temp = 0; l_length > l_tail_pos; l_temp++)
            {
                chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter][l_temp] = chr_h_note_new[l_tail_pos++];
            }
            chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter][l_temp] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter], chr_h_note_new + l_tail_pos, 35);
            chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter][36] = '\0';
        }
        l_counter++;
        l_tail_pos = l_tail_pos + 35;
    }

    Ms_SEnd(&chr_h_note_for_sm);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the last pointer in chr_h_note_for_sm (and therefore p_note_for_sm) to be NULL. The NULL values within the strings will not be seen by this if statement as that would require you to dereference p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]. The solution is to add a NULL pointer to the end of chr_h_note_for_sm before calling Ms_SEnd, like so:

```
chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter] = NULL;
/* l_counter is already at the correct index 
   due to the l_counter++ at the end of the while loop.*/
Ms_SEnd(&chr_h_note_for_sm);
```

Now the while loop will break as there is a NULL pointer in p_note_for_sm.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, concerning the usage of the `Ms_SEnd` function, it takes as parameter `char**` and you passed to it the address of `chr_h_note_for_sm` which is declared as `char *chr_h_note_for_sm[SMAXLINE]`.
You should pass to it just `chr_h_note_for_sm`, its type is already compatible with `char**`.

I recommend also using `strlen(chr_h_note_new)` to initialize `l_length`.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define SMAXLINE 200

int Ms_SEnd(char **p_note_for_sm) {
  int msg_line_no = 0;

  while (msg_line_no <= 200) {
    if ((p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]) != NULL) {
      printf("Msg In SM loop inside [%s]\n", p_note_for_sm[msg_line_no]);
      msg_line_no++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  char *chr_h_note_for_sm[SMAXLINE];
  char chr_h_note_1_new[8000] = "\0";
  char chr_h_note_new[8000] =
      "1 RECITE PREVIOUS MINUTES OF LAST AGM  2 DISCUSS THE BOD REPORT  3 "
      "DISCUSS THE AUDITORS REPORT  4 DISCUSS THE GENERAL BUDGET WITH THE "
      "PROFIT AND LOSS AND DISCUSS THE PERCENTAGE OF  CASH DIVIDENDS THAT WILL "
      "BE DISTRIBUTED  5 INDEMNIFY THE BOD  6 ELECT THE AUDITORS FOR THE YEAR "
      "2019  7 DISCUSS OTHER ISSUES";

  int l_tail_pos = 0;
  int l_counter = 0;
  int msg_line_no = 0;
  int rownum = 1;
  int l_temp = 0;
  int l_length = strlen(chr_h_note_new);

  while (l_tail_pos < l_length) {
    chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter] = (char *)calloc(36, sizeof(char));

    if ((l_length - l_tail_pos) < 35) {
      for (l_temp = 0; l_length > l_tail_pos; l_temp++) {
        chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter][l_temp] = chr_h_note_new[l_tail_pos++];
      }
      chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter][l_temp] = '\0';
    } else {
      strncpy(chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter], chr_h_note_new + l_tail_pos, 35);
      chr_h_note_for_sm[l_counter][36] = '\0';
    }
    l_counter++;
    l_tail_pos = l_tail_pos + 35;
  }

  Ms_SEnd(chr_h_note_for_sm);
  return 0;
}
```